# Subtracting one/more columns by a variable using shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

Is there a way where I can subtract a variable all the rows in a particular column using a shell script? In fact, is there one-liner that can perform this?

For eg : the variable 'discount' has the value 5, and the contents of the file are

```
32 Mars
40 Cadburys
25 Milky Bar
```

The desired output is

```
27 Mars
35 Cadburys
20 Milky Bar
```

The 'discount' keeps changing, and it must not be hardcoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$ awk '{print $1 - 5, $2}' file
27 Mars
35 Cadburys
20 Milky
```

Or even better:

```
$ discount=5
$ awk -v v=$discount '{print $1 - v, $2}' file
27 Mars
35 Cadburys
20 Milky
```

Comment: Hmm.. No. The value '5' is hardcoded. It might be accepted from the commandline and stored as, say $1.

Comment: But where is this value hardcoded? In a file? In my 2nd version I show how to give the var to `awk`, that is, with `-v v=$discount`

Comment: Yes, the second one. Thank! :) Just curious, why doesn't awk '{print $1 - $value}' file do the job?

Comment: Well `awk` does not accept the variables directly in the code, you have to pass them with `-v var=$bash_var` and then work with `var` (without `$`).

Comment: You are welcome! By the way, remember to mark the answer as accepted if you are already done. Cheers!

Comment: You could use the uglier `awk "{print \$1 - $discount, \$2}" file`, but it is error prone (I'm not sure I got even this example right); the posted solution is superior.